# Is there a way to force spark workers to use a distributed numpy version instead of the one installed on them?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, pyarrow

The situation is as follows: working on a enterprise cluster with spark 2.3, I want to run pandas_udf which requires pyarrow which requires numpy 0.14 (AFAIK).
Been able to distribute pyarrow (I think, no way of verifying this 100%):

```
 pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("pandas_udf_poc").config("spark.executor.instances","2")\
                                              .config("spark.executor.memory","8g")\
                                              .config("spark.driver.memory","8g")\
                                              .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize","8g")\
                                              .config("py-files", "pyarrow_depnd.zip")\
                                              .getOrCreate()  

spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("pyarrow_depnd.zip")
```

The zip is the result of pip install to dir and zipping it.

But pyarrow does not play along with the nodes numpy 0.13, I guess I could try and distribute a full env to all nodes, but my question is, is there a way to avoid this and make the node use a diffrent numpy (which is already distributed in the pyarrow zip)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, at the end, did not have to use a virtual env but could not avoid distributing a full copy of python (containing the needed dependencies) to all nodes.

First built a full copy of python (did use conda env, but you could probably use other ways):

```
conda create --prefix /home/me/env_conda_for_pyarrow
source activate /home/me/env_conda_for_pyarrow
conda install numpy 
conda install pyarrow
```

in this specific case had to open the conda-forge channel, prior to installs, in order to get the latest versions.

Second, zip the distribution:

```
zip -r env_conda_for_pyarrow.zip env_conda_for_pyarrow
```

Then use archives to distribute the zip and the env var PYSPARK_PYTHON to point to it:

```
import os, sys
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON']="dist_python/env_conda_for_pyarrow/bin/python"

import pyspark
spark = \
pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("pysaprk_python")\
.config("spark.yarn.dist.archives", "env_conda_for_pyarrow.zip#dist_python")\
.getOrCreate()

print spark.version, spark.sparkContext.master
```

That's it, done. Here are a few scripts I've used for testing:

```
def list_nodes_dir(x): # hack to see workers file dirs
    import os
    return os.listdir('dist_python')

spark.sparkContext.parallelize(range(1), 1).map(list_nodes_dir).collect()    



def npv(x): # hack to see workers numpy version
    import numpy as np
    return np.__version__

set(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(range(10), 10).map(npv).collect())



# spark documents example
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StringType
slen = pandas_udf(lambda s: s.str.len(), IntegerType())  

@pandas_udf(StringType())  
def to_upper(s):
    return s.str.upper()

@pandas_udf("integer", PandasUDFType.SCALAR)  
def add_one(x):
    return x + 1

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "John Doe", 21)], ("id", "name", "age"))  
df.select(slen("name").alias("slen(name)"), to_upper("name"), 
add_one("age")).show()
```